# Is there a way to stop notifications firing after a certain date?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, notifications

Currently I need my app to fire notifications twice a week for 6 or 12 weeks , I am using the UNUserNotificationCenter to fire my notifications. I have got them firing twice a week using a UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger which repeats on the certain day of week and time ok, but I cannot seem to figure out how to get them to stop after a certain date .

I have researched and the only thing i can see is to create them all at once, is there a max how many you can create at once, as I further develop my choices will get larger ie 5 times a week for 24 weeks.

Is there any way that this possible without having to create them all at once ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to stop notifications firing after a certain date?

If the user doesn't even open your app during the 6 or 12 weeks, you can't stop the notification.

If user use the app, after fire the notification at the first time, I think you can get the specific date after 6 or 12 weeks, let's say it `endDate`. So you can check the date between `nowDate` and `endDate` during app is running:

```
    if (nowDate < endDate)
    {
        // do nothing, still fire the notification
    }
    else
    {
        //cancle the notification
    }
```

> is there a max how many you can create at once

No, you can create as much as you want.

> Is there any way that this possible without having to create them all
>   at once ?

Here comes the same problem, if the user doesn't even open your app during the 6 or 12 weeks, how could you create the other notifications if you don't create them all
 at once?

So, I would recommend you to use a `remote-notification` and then you can control send or not send notification to certain user everyday.

Refer :The document [about-user-notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications?tabs=windows#about-user-notifications);

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have currently set up a class for the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate and in there im using 'Public override void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
{
completionHandler(UNNotifcationPresentationOptions.Alert);
}

Is there any way i can override this class to include my start and end date here?

Comment: Read the document about how to use this function: [handling-foreground-app-notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications?tabs=windows#handling-foreground-app-notifications)